# How to change subtitle's color & add background to it with mencoder/ffmpeg command line tools?

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04, subtitle, mencoder, srt

I want to burn a subtitle file with `.srt` format in Persian (-utf8) into a video file with `.mp4` format using mencoder. I'm using ubuntu 14.04. This command works for the simple task of burning subtitle on video file:

```
sudo mencoder input.mp4 -sub subtitle.srt -utf8 -o output.mp4 -oac pcm -ovc lavc
```

Now I want to change the color and font size of subtitle, and also add background for the subtitle. I've seen some commands here, like  `-ass-color <value>` ,  `-sub-bg-color` but They don't work together. -sub-bg-color works when I import the .srt file, and -ass-color works with .ass format. Also I don't want to convert .srt files to .ass.
Does anyone know how can I complete this line of command to do these changes I mentioned above?

Any equal command in ffmpeg is also wellcomed. I'm using mencoder just to avoid messing up with ffmpeg compiling process.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is too old. anyway it will help somebody.
if you have .srt file you can simple style the subtitle with ASS style format.

I have an example for you.

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:03,553
This text is styled <font color="#ffff00" size=14>very well</font>

2
00:00:03,553 --> 00:00:06,060
<b>Bold</b> or <i>Ittallic.</i>
```

Comment: Where is the documentation that identifies all the parameters available inside the `<font>` tag? What parameters are available?

Comment: According to the source of ffmpeg-4.4.4, the only attributes accepted are: `color`, `size` and `face`. Maybe other decoders accept more, but then you end up using features not available everywhere.